# Print 64bit pointer address in VS 2017?

Tags: c++, pointers, visual-studio-2017, 64-bit, memory-address

I'm trying to std::cout a pointer on an 64bit system in VS 2017, but I only see 4 bytes where I was expecting 8?

```
const char *tests = "Hello World";
using namespace std;
int main()
{
   stringstream convert;

   convert << (void*)tests << endl;

   string outs;

   convert >> outs;

   std::cout
        << std::hex
        << std::noshowbase
        << std::setw(2)
        << std::setfill('0')
        << std::endl
        << outs << "\n";

   return 0;
```

}

example output: 00342C30

What am I doing wrong?
Please forgive my ignorance. 
Its been a while since I've coded anything.

Comment: Does your project know it's being built for a 64 bit target?

Comment: Try printing its size using `sizeof`.

Comment: Also, you should try setting all of those manipulators on the `convert` stream. Using them after the pointer is stringified is pointless.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Silly me, I did set the target to x64 but I didn't realize that VS2017 placed the x64 product in a separate folder.